# Mindmeld gazetteer build failes with 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: mindmeld

Following docs from mindmeld.com([Step 7](https://www.mindmeld.com/docs/quickstart/07_train_the_natural_language_processing_classifiers.html)):

```
from mindmeld.components.nlp import NaturalLanguageProcessor
nlp = NaturalLanguageProcessor('.')
nlp.build()
```

Results in error:

```
self.build_gazetteer(gaz_name, force_reload=force_reload)
File "/home/sar/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mindmeld/resource_loader.py", line 214, in
build_gazetteer
mapping.get("entities", []), self.query_factory.normalize
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Obviously, list has no .get(), I assume nlp.build() should have made a dictionary, but fails to do so. Anyone else experienced this? Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.9.

EDIT: Found this old post of mine, worked it out. I don't remember details, but nlp doesn't support Python > 3.7, custom Python version in virtual environment fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was incompatible Python version for MindMeld, using Python 3.6 or 3.7 fixed this